# Identify string type

Tags: php, sql-server, hex

Hi everyone I've inherited a problem.

I've been given a SQL 2008 server DB where files are stored in bianryvar fields.

The entries start with 0x. Each entry is 43679 chars long of alphanumeric characters.

I know one of these is pdf.

I have a note from the previous worker that this might have to do with byte stream.

My task using my local copy is convert this string back into files. I need to migrate the data. I don't need a full program (it would be nice tho) but just a direction as to what this may be or some steps I could take to identify what I'm looking at.

Any info will help me.

Thanks.

Comment: The 0x means it is a hexadecimal value. It is probably binary encoded hex to make it shorter. Try converting the one you know is a PDF to binary and loading it as a pdf file.

Comment: I get this on the conversion. Input text for decoding must be in hexadecimal form (characters [a-f0-9 \n\r\t\-]) and its length has to be even.

Comment: Can you paste in maybe the first 5 or so characters?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the type of the file you could convert the hex to binary

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

Then you can find the file type using file_info:

```
// Check the mime type of the file against acceptable file types.
$file_info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);

$mime_type = finfo_buffer($file_info, $binary_string);
```

**Edit:** You might already be dealing with binary. Just try to code above without the conversion.